# Serial.readBytesUntil() gives garbage value and cause setup() function act like loop.

Tags: arrays, arduino, serial-port

I'am trying to read string using Serial.readBytesUntil() function. My code is here :

```
char *name_arr;
char *test = "Serial.begin is Ready";

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(test);
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.readBytesUntil('\r', name_arr, 10)){    
     Serial.println(name_arr);
     Serial.println();
  }
}
```

When I give only one digit as serial input , nothing happens.Serial.println() function prints nothing.

But when I give input more then two numerical digit like 15,12 etc , it started to print garbage values in infinite loop.
[image: This is output's screen shot:]

If I give character inputs like "asd" or use this code for loop() instead of previous one :
    `void loop(){
    while (Serial.available()>0){
        Serial.readBytesUntil('\r', name_arr, 10);
        Serial.println(name_arr);
        Serial.println();
    }`

Then it prints the whole string "test" except first two characters.But test is printed only in the setup function:
[image: creepy output]

It seems like setup() function run again and again .

**How can I save a string input in a character array (not in string class) ?**

How could a function can rerun the setup function and why initial two digits are not printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readBytesUntil` will store bytes in the second argument (see [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytesUntil)), but you have declared only a *pointer*, not an *array*.  A pointer defaults to address zero, so `readBytesUntil` was storing characters at address 0.  Bad, very bad.  This caused the reset, which looks like `setup` keeps running over and over.

You need to change the declaration to:

```
char name_array[11];
```

Also, don't forget that C-style strings (i.e., char arrays) need to be NUL-terminated.  `readBytesUntil` returns the number of characters it read, and you can use that return value to terminate the string:

```
size_t num_read = Serial.readBytesUntil('\r', name_arr, sizeof(name_arr)-1 ));
name_arr[ num_read ] = '\0'; // a zero byte, ASCII NUL
```

This is why it didn't print properly.  Notice that the declaration has an extra byte for the NUL ("11", not "10"), and the 3rd argument to `readBytesUntil` is the array size minus 1.

The total sketch:

```
char name_arr[11];
char *test = "Serial.begin is Ready";

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(test);
}

void loop(){
  while (Serial.available()) {
    size_t num_read = Serial.readBytesUntil('\r', name_arr, sizeof(name_arr)-1 );
    name_arr[num_read] = '\0';
    Serial.println(name_arr);
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot , now it's printing properly. except it prints again without first digit. Like I gave input "anklon" .. then it will print "anklon".That's fine , but  after this, it prints "nklon" automatically . and it's do not printing name_arr[0] character :3

Comment: You didn't post your new code, but I was able to reproduce it.  Did you NUL-terminate the string after `num_read = Serial.readBytes...`?  I added the entire sketch above

Comment: Yes, I add NULL terminate.  My code is actually same as yours.

Comment: In your Serial Monitor window, does the pull-down in the lower-right hand corner say "Both NL and CR"?  Just to the left of the baud rate pull-down.  This will cause it to print two things: the line you entered, up to the NL, and then an empty line for the extra CR that the Serial Monitor sent.  If you don't have the `name_arr[num_read]='\0'` in there, then the second print shows "nklon" because the CR stepped on the 'a'.  Are you sure it uploaded ok?